# Using interpolation function

Tags: interpolation

I have data for the below figure and want to determine the values along the diagonal and plot a line graph with the x axis.

[image]

```
 xvalues = Table[uzL1Mo1[[i, 1]], {i, Length[uzL1Mo1]}];
 yvalues = Table[uzL1Mo1[[i, 2]], {i, Length[uzL1Mo1]}];
 Min[xvalues]
 Max[xvalues]
 Min[yvalues]
 Max[yvalues]
 m1 = Max[yvalues] - Min[yvalues]
 m2 = (Max[xvalues] - Min[xvalues])
 m = m1/m2
 numa = 499


 xlist = Table[Min[xvalues] + i m2/numa, {i, 0, numa}];

  

 The data is attached below


    {{14.2441, 24.4802, -0.54407}, {11.7597, 19.6033, -0.52572}, {14.4097,
    21.3246, -0.53577}, {17.0598, 23.0459, -0.53995}, {19.7099, 
    24.7671, -0.5362}, {9.27522, 14.7264, -0.50511}, {11.9253, 
    16.4477, -0.5123}, {14.5754, 18.1689, -0.52179}, {17.2254, 
    19.8902, -0.5287}, {19.8755, 21.6115, -0.52949}, {22.5255, 
    23.3327, -0.52376}, {25.1756, 25.054, -0.51418}, {6.79079, 
    9.84947, -0.50695}, {9.44085, 11.5707, -0.50047}, {12.0909, 
    13.292, -0.50095}, {14.741, 15.0133, -0.50694}, {17.391, 
    16.7345, -0.51418}, {20.0411, 18.4558, -0.5182}, {22.6912, 
    20.1771, -0.51687}, {25.3412, 21.8983, -0.51155}, {27.9913, 
    23.6196, -0.50592}, {30.6414, 25.3409, -0.50379}, {4.30635, 
    4.97255, -0.5287}, {6.95642, 6.69382, -0.51418}, {9.60648, 
    8.41508, -0.50167}, {12.2565, 10.1364, -0.49538}, {14.9066, 
    11.8576, -0.49628}, {17.5567, 13.5789, -0.50167}, {20.2067, 
    15.3002, -0.50695}, {22.8568, 17.0214, -0.50869}, {25.5069, 
    18.7427, -0.50666}, {28.1569, 20.464, -0.5037}, {30.807, 
    22.1852, -0.50365}, {33.4571, 23.9065, -0.50869}, {36.1071, 
    25.6278, -0.5182}, {1.82192, 0.095626, -0.54407}, {4.47198, 
    1.81689, -0.53577}, {7.12205, 3.53816, -0.52179}, {9.77211, 
    5.25943, -0.50694}, {12.4222, 6.98069, -0.49628}, {15.0722, 
    8.70196, -0.49267}, {17.7223, 10.4232, -0.49538}, {20.3724, 
    12.1445, -0.50047}, {23.0224, 13.8658, -0.50379}, {25.6725, 
    15.587, -0.50365}, {28.3226, 17.3083, -0.50169}, {30.9726, 
    19.0296, -0.50169}, {33.6227, 20.7508, -0.50666}, {36.2728, 
    22.4721, -0.51687}, {38.9228, 24.1934, -0.52949}, {41.5729, 
    25.9146, -0.53995}, {7.28768, 0.382504, -0.52572}, {9.93774, 
    2.10377, -0.5123}, {12.5878, 3.82504, -0.50095}, {15.2379, 
    5.54631, -0.49538}, {17.8879, 7.26757, -0.49628}, {20.538, 
    8.98884, -0.50095}, {23.1881, 10.7101, -0.50511}, {25.8381, 
    12.4314, -0.50592}, {28.4882, 14.1526, -0.5037}, {31.1383, 
    15.8739, -0.50169}, {33.7883, 17.5952, -0.5037}, {36.4384, 
    19.3164, -0.51155}, {39.0884, 21.0377, -0.52376}, {41.7385, 
    22.759, -0.5362}, {12.7534, 0.669382, -0.50511}, {15.4035, 
    2.39065, -0.50047}, {18.0536, 4.11192, -0.50167}, {20.7036, 
    5.83318, -0.50694}, {23.3537, 7.55445, -0.5123}, {26.0038, 
    9.27572, -0.51418}, {28.6538, 10.997, -0.51155}, {31.3039, 
    12.7183, -0.50666}, {33.9539, 14.4395, -0.50365}, {36.604, 
    16.1608, -0.50592}, {39.2541, 17.8821, -0.51418}, {18.2192, 
    0.95626, -0.50695}, {20.8693, 2.67753, -0.51418}, {23.5193, 
    4.39879, -0.52179}, {26.1694, 6.12006, -0.52572}, {28.8194, 
    7.84133, -0.52376}, {31.4695, 9.5626, -0.51687}, {34.1196, 
    11.2839, -0.50869}, {36.7696, 13.0051, -0.50379}, {23.6849, 
   1.24314, -0.5287}, {26.335, 2.9644, -0.53577}, {28.9851, 
   4.68567, -0.5362}, {31.6351, 6.40694, -0.52949}, {34.2852, 
   8.12821, -0.5182}, {29.1507, 1.53002, -0.54407}, {31.8008, 
    3.25128, -0.53995}}
```

in each list contain x value, y value and data( displacement of atoms). I believe interpolation function can be used to determine the values along the diagonal line. Not sure how. Please assist me with this. Thanks

Can we use something like this

```
test2 = Table[{x, y, z} = i; {{x, y}, z}, {i, uzL1Mo1}];
fun = Interpolation[test2];
```

Comment: Are you able to provide more data? I am getting errors because there are not enough data points. If this is a problem I can try something else.

Comment: Sorry, for this system these are the all data points available. Thank you very much for trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  test2 = Table[{x, y, z} = i; {{x, y}, z}, {i, uzL1Mo1}];
  Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
  mesh = ToElementMesh[test2[[All, 1]]]
  mesh["Wireframe"]
```

ToElementMesh::femimq: The element mesh has insufficient quality of -4.38212*10^-15. A quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of element incidents or self-intersecting elements.

```
   q = mesh["Quality"];
   pos = Position[q, _?(# <= Min[q] &)]

   badTriangle = 
   First[Extract[ElementIncidents[mesh["MeshElements"]], pos]]
   mesh["Coordinates"][[badTriangle]]

   Area[Triangle[mesh["Coordinates"][[badTriangle]]]]

   mesh = ToElementMesh[
   test2[[All, 1]] + RandomReal[{-10^-8, 10^-8}, {Length[test2]}]];
   int= ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, test2[[All, 2]]];
```

I have done these steps according to the [enter link description here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65693/interpolation-function-error-interpolationfemimq-and-interpolationfememtlq)

Now I need to get a table of x values (along the diagonal) and corresponding data values

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

I now have a full answer to this question. See below

**Old Answer**

This is an answer that is a beginning but fails so perhaps it should be another question. I am attempting to build on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235747/12558) and the associated question where the method works.

I start with your data

```
data = {{14.2441, 24.4802, -0.54407}, {11.7597, 
    19.6033, -0.52572}, {14.4097, 21.3246, -0.53577}, {17.0598, 
    23.0459, -0.53995}, {19.7099, 24.7671, -0.5362}, {9.27522, 
    14.7264, -0.50511}, {11.9253, 16.4477, -0.5123}, {14.5754, 
    18.1689, -0.52179}, {17.2254, 19.8902, -0.5287}, {19.8755, 
    21.6115, -0.52949}, {22.5255, 23.3327, -0.52376}, {25.1756, 
    25.054, -0.51418}, {6.79079, 9.84947, -0.50695}, {9.44085, 
    11.5707, -0.50047}, {12.0909, 13.292, -0.50095}, {14.741, 
    15.0133, -0.50694}, {17.391, 16.7345, -0.51418}, {20.0411, 
    18.4558, -0.5182}, {22.6912, 20.1771, -0.51687}, {25.3412, 
    21.8983, -0.51155}, {27.9913, 23.6196, -0.50592}, {30.6414, 
    25.3409, -0.50379}, {4.30635, 4.97255, -0.5287}, {6.95642, 
    6.69382, -0.51418}, {9.60648, 8.41508, -0.50167}, {12.2565, 
    10.1364, -0.49538}, {14.9066, 11.8576, -0.49628}, {17.5567, 
    13.5789, -0.50167}, {20.2067, 15.3002, -0.50695}, {22.8568, 
    17.0214, -0.50869}, {25.5069, 18.7427, -0.50666}, {28.1569, 
    20.464, -0.5037}, {30.807, 22.1852, -0.50365}, {33.4571, 
    23.9065, -0.50869}, {36.1071, 25.6278, -0.5182}, {1.82192, 
    0.095626, -0.54407}, {4.47198, 1.81689, -0.53577}, {7.12205, 
    3.53816, -0.52179}, {9.77211, 5.25943, -0.50694}, {12.4222, 
    6.98069, -0.49628}, {15.0722, 8.70196, -0.49267}, {17.7223, 
    10.4232, -0.49538}, {20.3724, 12.1445, -0.50047}, {23.0224, 
    13.8658, -0.50379}, {25.6725, 15.587, -0.50365}, {28.3226, 
    17.3083, -0.50169}, {30.9726, 19.0296, -0.50169}, {33.6227, 
    20.7508, -0.50666}, {36.2728, 22.4721, -0.51687}, {38.9228, 
    24.1934, -0.52949}, {41.5729, 25.9146, -0.53995}, {7.28768, 
    0.382504, -0.52572}, {9.93774, 2.10377, -0.5123}, {12.5878, 
    3.82504, -0.50095}, {15.2379, 5.54631, -0.49538}, {17.8879, 
    7.26757, -0.49628}, {20.538, 8.98884, -0.50095}, {23.1881, 
    10.7101, -0.50511}, {25.8381, 12.4314, -0.50592}, {28.4882, 
    14.1526, -0.5037}, {31.1383, 15.8739, -0.50169}, {33.7883, 
    17.5952, -0.5037}, {36.4384, 19.3164, -0.51155}, {39.0884, 
    21.0377, -0.52376}, {41.7385, 22.759, -0.5362}, {12.7534, 
    0.669382, -0.50511}, {15.4035, 2.39065, -0.50047}, {18.0536, 
    4.11192, -0.50167}, {20.7036, 5.83318, -0.50694}, {23.3537, 
    7.55445, -0.5123}, {26.0038, 9.27572, -0.51418}, {28.6538, 
    10.997, -0.51155}, {31.3039, 12.7183, -0.50666}, {33.9539, 
    14.4395, -0.50365}, {36.604, 16.1608, -0.50592}, {39.2541, 
    17.8821, -0.51418}, {18.2192, 0.95626, -0.50695}, {20.8693, 
    2.67753, -0.51418}, {23.5193, 4.39879, -0.52179}, {26.1694, 
    6.12006, -0.52572}, {28.8194, 7.84133, -0.52376}, {31.4695, 
    9.5626, -0.51687}, {34.1196, 11.2839, -0.50869}, {36.7696, 
    13.0051, -0.50379}, {23.6849, 1.24314, -0.5287}, {26.335, 
    2.9644, -0.53577}, {28.9851, 4.68567, -0.5362}, {31.6351, 
    6.40694, -0.52949}, {34.2852, 8.12821, -0.5182}, {29.1507, 
    1.53002, -0.54407}, {31.8008, 3.25128, -0.53995}};
```

Now we should be able to make a mesh and use an interpolation function based on the mesh as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[data[[All, {1, 2}]]];
int = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, data[[All, 3]]];
```

Sadly we get some fatal errors
[image]

We do get a mesh

```
Show[mesh["Wireframe"]]
```

[image]

There are, apparently, not enough points to work with so we have to stop here.

Hopefully this is the beginning of a solution not the end of my attempt. I am hoping someone can finish this off.

**Edit**

**New Answer**

We now have a workaround for the the poor quality mesh. See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277399/12558).

The procedure is to select all the good triangles and drop the bad one. I start by extracting the coordinates from data and then make the bad mesh. The position of all the good triangles is then found and a new mesh made with those. Here is the code.

```
dd = data[[All, {1, 2}]];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[dd];
pts = mesh["Coordinates"];
triang = mesh["MeshElements"][[1, 1]];
quali = mesh["Quality"][[1]];
pos = Position[quali, _?(# > 10^-5 &)] // Flatten;
meshNew = 
  ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> pts, 
   "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[triang[[pos]]]}];
```

Now we can make the interpolation function using the new mesh. I then plot this using many points.

```
int = ElementMeshInterpolation[{meshNew}, data[[All, 3]]];
Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] meshNew, PlotPoints -> {100, 100}]
```

[image]

The reason for using many points is to see if the interpolation is working and also to see how good it is. Only linear interpolation is available on an  irregular region. You can see the "flats" in the surface.

As this is an irregular region it is not clear what you mean by a diagonal so I assume some end points for the diagonal and make the equation of a line going through the end points. This is checked by over-plotting on the mesh in red.

```
{x1, y1} = {1.82192`, 0.095626`};
{x2, y2} = {41.5729`, 25.9146`};
f[x_] := Evaluate[y1 + (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) (x - x1)];
Show[meshNew["Wireframe"], Plot[f[x], {x, x1, x2}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Now we can plot along your diagional

```
Plot[int[x, f[x]], {x, x1, x2}]
```

[image]

Is this what you need?

Comment: @user21 Can you help here? This looks like something you know about.

Comment: `ElementMeshQuality[mesh]` shows poor meshquality for some elements!

Comment: Sorry. These are the only data available for this system

Comment: Thank you very much for all the comments

Comment: @Shen Please see full answer and up vote, and select as appropriate.

Comment: (+1) @Shen  He seems no enough scores to up vote.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed.

Comment: @Hugh Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure what you meant by up vote. how can I do .

Comment: Up votes are the way this site works. You give up votes (arrows on the right of the answer) to indicate that this is helpful. If you get the answer that you need to your question you select the big tick beside the answer.